# flutter bloc_test show incorrect expected state

Tags: flutter, bloc-test

I am having issues with bloc_test, the expected does not match with the code.

**

> Expected: [
> AuthenticationState:AuthenticationState(RequestStatus.initial,
> RequestStatus.loading, RequestStatus.initial, null, null, null, null),
> AuthenticationState:AuthenticationState(RequestStatus.initial,
> RequestStatus.failed, RequestStatus.initial, null, An unknown error
> has occurred, null, null)
> ]

> Actual: [
> AuthenticationState:AuthenticationState(RequestStatus.loading,
> RequestStatus.initial, RequestStatus.initial, null, null, null, null),
> AuthenticationState:AuthenticationState(RequestStatus.failed,
> RequestStatus.initial, RequestStatus.initial, null, An unknown error
> has occurred, null, null)
> ]

> Which: at location [0] is AuthenticationState:<AuthenticationState(RequestStatus.loading,
> RequestStatus.initial, RequestStatus.initial, null, null, null, null)>
> instead of
> AuthenticationState:<AuthenticationState(RequestStatus.initial,
> RequestStatus.loading, RequestStatus.initial, null, null, null, null)>

**

The above is the error bloc_test throws, even though from the code the expected is supposed to be the same as actual.

Below is the test

```
class MockAuthenticationRepository extends Mock
    implements AuthenticationRepository {}

void main() {
  late AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc;
  late MockAuthenticationRepository mockAuthenticationRepository;

  setUp(() {
    mockAuthenticationRepository = MockAuthenticationRepository();
    authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc(
        authenticationRepository: mockAuthenticationRepository);
  });

  tearDown(() => authenticationBloc.close());

  group("login/signup with phone number", () {
    blocTest("failed login/signup",
        wait: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        build: () => authenticationBloc,
        act: (bloc) {
          when(() => mockAuthenticationRepository
                  .signInWithPhoneNumber("123456789"))
              .thenAnswer((invocation) async => const NetworkResponse(
                  status: RequestStatus.failed,
                  data: Constants.unknownErrorMessage));
          bloc.add(const RequestOtp(phoneNumber: '123456789'));
        },
        expect: () => [
              const AuthenticationState(
                  signInWithPhoneNumberStatus: RequestStatus.loading),
              const AuthenticationState(
                  errorText: Constants.unknownErrorMessage,
                  signInWithPhoneNumberStatus: RequestStatus.failed)
            ]);
  });
}
```

This is the state class

```
///The state class
class AuthenticationState extends Equatable {
  final RequestStatus requestOtpStatus;
  final RequestStatus signInWithPhoneNumberStatus;
  final RequestStatus verifySignInWithPhoneNumberStatus;
  final String? verificationId;
  final String? errorText;
  final int? resendToken;
  final UserCredential? userCredential;

  const AuthenticationState({
    this.requestOtpStatus = RequestStatus.initial,
    this.verifySignInWithPhoneNumberStatus = RequestStatus.initial,
    this.signInWithPhoneNumberStatus = RequestStatus.initial,
    this.verificationId,
    this.errorText,
    this.resendToken,
    this.userCredential,
  });

  AuthenticationState copyWith({
    RequestStatus? signInWithPhoneNumberStatus,
    RequestStatus? verifySignInWithPhoneNumberStatus,
    String? verificationId,
    String? errorText,
    int? resendToken,
    UserCredential? userCredential,
  }) {
    return AuthenticationState(
      requestOtpStatus:
          signInWithPhoneNumberStatus ?? this.signInWithPhoneNumberStatus,
      verifySignInWithPhoneNumberStatus: verifySignInWithPhoneNumberStatus ??
          this.verifySignInWithPhoneNumberStatus,
      verificationId: verificationId ?? this.verificationId,
      errorText: errorText ?? this.errorText,
      resendToken: resendToken ?? this.resendToken,
      userCredential: userCredential ?? this.userCredential,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        requestOtpStatus,
        signInWithPhoneNumberStatus,
        verifySignInWithPhoneNumberStatus,
        verificationId,
        errorText,
        resendToken,
        userCredential,
      ];
}
```

and the bloc

```
    ///The bloc
class AuthenticationBloc extends Bloc<OnboardingEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  AuthenticationBloc({required this.authenticationRepository})
      : super(const AuthenticationState()) {
    on<RequestOtp>(_mapRequestOtpEventToState);
    on<VerifyOtp>(_mapVerifyOtpEventToState);
    on<ResendOtp>(_mapResendOtpEventToState);
  }

  final AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository;

  void _mapRequestOtpEventToState(
      RequestOtp event, Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(signInWithPhoneNumberStatus: RequestStatus.loading));
    final response =
        await authenticationRepository.signInWithPhoneNumber(event.phoneNumber);

    if (response.status != RequestStatus.success) {
      final data = response.data;
      emit(state.copyWith(
          signInWithPhoneNumberStatus: response.status, errorText: data));
    } else {
      //success
      final data = response.data as List<dynamic>;
      emit(state.copyWith(
          signInWithPhoneNumberStatus: response.status,
          verificationId: data[0],
          resendToken: data[1]));
    }
  }
}
```

I have asked chatgpt but it just keeps throwing my code right back to me, i don't understand why the state expected (from the log) does not match with my code but the actual is does.